# Do I still need to use virtual memory?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

I would have thought this was already asked but I can't seem to find it.

At what point do I no longer need virtual memory enabled?  With 4GB of RAM I see that the computer rarely uses anywhere near all of it.  At that point virtual memory isn't strictly necessary.  Is there danger in turning it off?  Are there features I'll lose if I do?

Comment: **Attention:** There is only a limited amount of memory given to drivers, called the [`non-paged` and `paged` pool](http://bit.ly/rttIee) memory sections. A page file is necessary for when the paged section gets full, as a gamer I have seen a game complain about paged pool memory just because I had my page file disabled on a 8 GB system. Conclusion: **Page files are necessary, they prevent paged pool depletion and actually [do speed up](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-throw-those-paging-files-away.html) your system.**

Comment: Let's say you have 4GB RAM and 4GB swap. Following this logic means when you have 8GB RAM you don't need a swap. I personally recommand disabling swap on a desktop PC if you have 16GB of RAM or more (in 2023). Because swap reduces the lifetime of your SSD or HDD.

Comment: You cannot disable *virtual memory*. It's an integral part of modern operating systems. All of them. You can minimize swap/page file size. That's what the answers are about, even though often phrased incorrectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since memory is not exactly a sparse resource on desktop PCs / laptops anymore, I doubt that most programs can handle out-of-memory conditions gracefully and will crash instead.

So: **Dangerous? Yes**, if your 4GB are used up somehow and you have no pagefile, applications may start to crash.

And as shown in Zoran's example it may be hard to identify the problem later on.

The article, that Ram refers to, also states, that turning swapping off **usually doesn't improve speed and may do the opposite instead**:

> So while there may be some workloads that perform better with no paging file, in general having one will mean more usable memory being available to the system

Comment: I will have to dig up the article on MS's site, but MS does say you should always have a pagefile.  Even on high memory systems, not having one can make your machine run slower.

Answer (score 10):

See [Mark Russinovich's article](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) on Virtual Memory. That should give you a good pointer about Virtual Memory.

Here's a useful excerpt from the link

> So how do you know how much commit charge your workloads require? You might have noticed in the screenshots that Windows tracks that number and Process Explorer shows it: Peak Commit Charge. To optimally size your paging file you should start all the applications you run at the same time, load typical data sets, and then note the commit charge peak (or look at this value after a period of time where you know maximum load was attained). Set the paging file minimum to be that value minus the amount of RAM in your system (if the value is negative, pick a minimum size to permit the kind of crash dump you are configured for). If you want to have some breathing room for potentially large commit demands, set the maximum to double that number.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to leave the virtual memory settings to their default. I have 8GB of RAM and turned virtual memory off thinking I would gain in speed (because of no swapping), but it turns out that made my system less stable (and I did this on 2 machines, similar result). I was experiencing one BSOD per week approximately, on both machines. I started examining the minidumps produced and found out that all the BSODs were triggered by a call to a routine called KiPageFault. So I tried setting the virtual memory settings back to their defaults, and the regular BSODs disappeared.

Took me quite a while to correlate the 2, and I have no actual evidence that the fact that I turned off virtual memory caused the BSODs, but my machines were more stable after I turned it back on...

Answer (score 3):

[This classic post](https://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine) on ServerFault has some good points. For only 4GB I'd leave the pagefile alone, and the space involved on the disk is minor in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Hp laptop gw-150000d. Ryzen 3, integrated amd graphics 2 GB, WIN 11, 16GB RAM, 1T HDD

I tried allocating VM until it was at the minimum ( 16 MB ) and it ran the same as it did with 4 gb. I then disabled it completely which left me with 13.9 Gb usable ram. Boot up times were the same from a cold start ( HDD ) however once I logged in I noticed there was less then 1 second delay in ANY system action I took. I adjusted settings with lightning speed. Played games ( skyrim ) on the max settings. the only slow down WAS at loading points ( going from open world to a cave or city ) from reading from the HDD.

So I played with each idea. Allocating virtual ram up and down until it was 0.

I listed all hardware specs so my experiment may be recreated.

In my personal opinion, through the use of the scientific method. I know that virtual memory is COMPLETE TRASH. Especially considering that this laptop 299$ ( the cheapest one at office depot) can support up to 128 GB OF RAM... VM Is like having a tiny dinosaur using its fingers for math in your pc

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173597)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your workload is. I've set up a bunch of diskless frontends for a web application. They network booted and ran everything they needed within 8GB of ram.

I've also used windows (98 probably) with 32MB and no pagefile - of course you have to live in that memory space and limit your apps to suit the resources.

You do want to make sure that there is some extra RAM for the disk cache, otherwise performance can become horrible.

I seem to recall that there are some programs that won't run without VM, but I have no idea what they were

Answer (score 0):

As the majority said, I confirm you should keep virtual memory.

Especially while:

- Yes, memory is more afordable, but also disk space is cheap nowadays, so 6GB won't make any difference.
- More and more system disks are SSDs, and while it's not as fast as DRAM, its access is **very very** fast compared to our old HDDs.

But you should define it **as a fixed size** virtual memory, not a dynamic one as generated by default on Windows.

I'd recommend the number of 1.5x the physical memory size, but this is an old rule of thumb I follow, and I can't confirm you it's still valid.

But if you're VERY concerned about your data security - at a really **high** level - then yes, you could remove the swap file and disable it, because this could be a concern, even if, I guess, recent systems may encrypt this file contents also.

(Even if coldboot attacks can directly get the contents of your DRAM even if your PC is turned off, but it's another story, and probably not having a swap file is better in this **very specific** level of security).

*I sincerely hope this can help - I'm not familiar with SE.*

Answer (score -3):

Well, Steve, interesting that you should ask that.

I will tell you a little secret: the point at which you needed virtual memory was never. Virtual memory was an insanely incompetent idea created by a bunch of academics who knew zero about practical computing systems, and ANY computer will function vastly better if it can be made to run without VM.

Now, you might ask, if VM is useless and harmful, why do most big modern operating systems use it? The short answer to this question is that the people deciding whether to use VM or not at Microsoft, Apple and IBM were even more stupid and inexperienced than the academics who invented VM and wanted to adopt it based on the same, completely incorrect assumptions that the academics had when they invented it. We could start talking about those assumptions and misconceptions, but unfortunately, if they were easy to understand and describe we would not have the VM problem in the first place.

Getting back to you. Unfortunately, just like the aforementioned tardnoggins at Apple and Microsoft, you have your own misconceptions, namely the idea that you can turn off VM. Of course, you cannot turn it off, that would defeat the whole purpose of screwing you if you could just turn it off. When people do something really stupid, they always make sure it is irreversible. After all, if everybody could just turn off VM, they would, and that would make the bozos who created it look pretty stupid wouldn't it? They prevented this possibility by making it unremovable, kind of like Microsoft made Internet Explorer unremovable.

What you can do is limit the size of the page file, which of course should be set to whatever the minimum is, hopefully 0. Virtual Memory is still there, but at least you can reduce it from very very very slow to just very very slow by asking it to not involve the disk drive in the insanity.

---

I guess I will briefly discuss why VM is a bad idea for the 1% who actually care, even though it is not what the OP asked.

Out of the box, VM is bad because it indirects memory so it slows down any memory-involved operations by 5x to 10x. If a disk is involved, then the slow down becomes much more pronounced, anywhere from 10x to 100x slower. The net result is that a computer using a VM is generally AT LEAST 10x slower than the same computer which does not use VM. So, that is the bad. Also, it makes the computer more complicated, because now there are two different sets of addresses, hardware addresses and virtual addresses.

The supposed benefits of using a VM are two: (1) it creates a flat memory addressing scheme, and (2) it allows the amount of memory to be increased dynamically by moving rarely used memory to disk. On paper these sound like great advantages, but in the real world they do not come close to compensating for the performance degradation.

(Re 1) Virtually all computer languages using memory managers (C, Java, etc). Therefore, application programmers do not care whether there is a flat memory space or not, because the memory manager takes care of that. As far as the memory managers themselves are concerned, writing a manager which can use a discontinuous set of memory addresses is only marginally more difficult than one which does not. So the advantage of (1) is more or less inconsequential to 99% of programmers.

(Re 2) In real life, VMs that use disks frequently use the disk even though they supposed to "rarely" use the disk. Anyone who has watched the disk thrash in the early days (1980s) knows this. Modern Windows computers are so polluted with VMs and OS-related garbage that they thrash continuously, even if no applications are running at all. The advantage that the VM prevents the user from getting an "out of memory" error, is a false advantage. I would much rather have my computer run faster and get the occasional out of memory error. It is true that modern computers do not give out of memory errors--they just slow down and become completely unusable so you have to reboot the whole machine. With direct memory access, you just close the offending program and keep going, a much better way of doing things.

Comment: Virtual memory allows a great many good things. If you didn't have virtual memory then you would have to have enough RAM to hold every byte of code and data that every process on your system defines, whether or not it was ever actually referenced. Since most programs spend 90% of their time using 10% of their code and data this would be a huge waste. You would also lose many other useful things, which the comment format here doesn't give me room to outline. The reason we haven't abandoned virtual memory is that it's still a really, really good idea. Even in "practical computing systems".

Comment: @RickBrant You sound like the idiot electrical engineers from Intel and IBM I use to have to listen to back in the 1980s trying to explain why VM was a good idea. I remember back when IBM came out with OS/2, which was the first operating system brain damaged with VM, having to listen to them explain why it was such a great idea. Well, thank god OS/2 died, but unfortunately VM kept going, like a zombie, so here it is 2017 and I am still listening to this nonsense.I'll bet dollars to donuts you don't have a CS degree, do you? That's the joke part. 99% of the guys promoting VM are not programmers

Comment: I was a dual major in fact, CS/EE, at one of the best tech schools on the west coast. Today I am mostly a programmer, but I do interact with hardware types. Now, do you have a cogent rebuttal to the point that it would be very wasteful to have to keep every last byte of code and data a program defines in RAM at all times, whether it needs it or not? Because virtual memory avoids that. Or are you going to continue with personal attacks that amount to "you must be an idiot"?

Comment: Oh, and re _"OS/2, which was the first operating system brain damaged with VM,"_ Um, no, not by about two decades. Maybe the first widely-used OS for PCs. (But not the first for "personal computers".)

Comment: I tried swithching VM off and whereas the hard drive used to thrash incessantly, and it took up to two minutes to settle after log-in it now doesn't, and the system boots in 12 seconds including log-in. Watching Task Manager seems to show 2GB headroom in 8GB of RAM on a laptop running W10. So far no BSOD. It still shows a Paged Pool of around 580MB / Non Paged around 300 MB with 4GB RAM committed. Quick as a flash loading web pages which it used to struggle with. I am not a gamer though. Worked for me so far. It also runs much cooler.

Comment: @Tyler Durden Sorry it seems to get downvoted - I upvoted it because the performance remains impressive. Four different browsers all open together with a dozen pages including video and in the end when it finally ran out of memory, no BSOD just a polite message from a browser that it had run out of memory, which went away as soon as I made a little space. Sorry to see this getting downvoted as it clearly works extremely well.

Comment: As a matter of interest (perhaps) I did need to activate virtual memory when archving a huge number of small files to a memory stick. Even with only a small amount of virtual memory it could carry on but without it, it overfilled the RAM. Apart from that, it is still blindingly fast and running cooler without virtual memory.