# Can I disable virtual memory?

Tags: windows, performance, memory, virtual-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I still need to use virtual memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/55147/do-i-still-need-to-use-virtual-memory)

Suppose I have a system with 8 gigs of RAM. I have used systems with less than that including physical RAM and virtual memory.

So, why not just disable virtual memory on my monster machine? Wouldn't that improve performance? Or is there some reason to continue using virtual memory?

Comment: fyi, [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) is not the same as [page file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

Comment: @grawity, I would like to give you ten comment upvotes.

Comment: There is only a limited amount of memory given to drivers, called the [`non-paged` and `paged` pool](http://bit.ly/rttIee) memory sections. A page file is necessary for when the paged section gets full, as a gamer I have seen a game complain about paged pool memory just because I had my page file disabled on a 8 GB system. **They are necessary, they prevent paged pool depletion and actually [do speed up](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-throw-those-paging-files-away.html) your system.**

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine/23684#23684) excellent response to a similar question on ServerFault is very informative - have a read, you might be surprised but keeping the page file active is still a good idea even with 8Gb RAM because it does a more than just pretend to be "extra RAM".